Can PieCloudDB export the results of a query to a CSV file?
PostgreSQL can use copy command to achieve it(e.g. Copy (Select * From table) To 'test.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;). Can PieCloudDB support this feature? Or is there any other method to export the results of a query to a CSV file?

You don’t need to use complicated commands to achieve this. In the PieCloudDB cloud native platform, you can just click “Export as CSV” as picture below to get the results CSV file directly.

